# Unified price for a class of products?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

Is there a way to define a class of prices for products, so that I can create a discount across all of them at once? For example my store has chain chokers, of which there are single chain chokers and double chain chokers. The single chain chokers vary in price, but the double chain chokers are all the same price. Is there a way to define a price class for all double chain chokers to share, so that later if I change the price I only need to change it in one place?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mass update feature in the product grid would be helpful, although it's not exactly what you asked for.

in the catalog -> product overview, you can select the products you want to change and then make a massupdate on the attributes (you can also filter first to have only your desired products in the grid and then select all for example)

After you have selected your products, go to the selectbox in the top right corner of the grid, select update attributes and hit the submit button next to it.

Then check the change checkbox under the price attribute and you can update the price (or any other attribute) for as many products as you need